# What's the purpose of actions/checkout@v3, when the repository is already checked out on job start?

Tags: github, gitlab, continuous-integration, github-actions, action

I've previously used GitLab, where I didn't checkout the repository explicitly. Instead it was done automatically by the pipeline.

Thus, I was surprised that almost all GitHub Actions workflows use e.g. `actions/checkout@v3`.

But what's the purpose besides checking out a different repository?

As seen from the below screenshot, my repository is already checked out, when the job starts:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, this action will check-out to the SHA for that workflow’s event (such as push and pull_request). Otherwise, uses the default branch (usually main or master in a standard repository).

> You should use the checkout action any time your workflow will use the repository's code.
>
> https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions#understanding-the-workflow-file

> This action checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your workflow can access it.
>
> https://github.com/actions/checkout

So you can specify the repo, branch, path, submodule and so on to which you can checkout. Also you can use `fetch-depth` to include git history as necessary.

Also note, that it's cloning the files to `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE`.

Comment: Thank you @RobinThomas. By **Otherwise, uses the default branch (usually main or master in a standard repository).** - you mean that GitHub's default behaviour is to clone the default branch? So, what I'm seeing in the screen is actually the tip of the `master` branch? Could you elaborate on `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE`? Is this different from where GitHub normally clones the repository (in my case: `/__w/lddprobff/lddprobff`)

Comment: There is no defined location for `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE`, since thats set by the GitHub runner. But looks like `/__w/lddprobff/lddprobff` is the `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` in this case.

Comment: If you have a PR that triggers a workflow, then the default branch will be the branch of that PR, and not the default branch.

Comment: I think you mean the PR source branch. But, what you're saying is that GitHub Actions by default clones the default branch, except when triggered by a PR?

Comment: Yes, PR source branch.

Comment: No, `actions/checkout` is an official action from GitHub to clone the repo to the workspace of the Actions runner. That action will use the PR source branch /commit (if available) or use the default branch.

Comment: @Shuzheng Does that clarify everything? If yes, can you accept my answer? Thanks :)

Comment: I will accept it, but what's the default checkout behavior, when not using the `actions/checkout`? I observe my repository already checked out, when the workflow is executed. When can I avoid using the action?

Comment: Why does `actions/checout` checkout the default branch, if running a workflow for a different branch without an associated PR?

Comment: It wont. It will use the branch/tag that triggered the workflow.

Comment: Nice, but you don't know the clone behavior, when not using `actions/checkout`?

Comment: No Github recommends to use `actions/checkout` if we need to use our repo in our workflow. So not exactly sure about this clone behaviour. Maybe github could change this behaviour in the future though.

Answer (score 4):

Without the checkout action GitHub wont clone your repository and you will get an empty folder. You can check this with a very basic action.yml

```
name: My Workflow
on: push
jobs:
  myjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: just a simple ls command
        runs: ls -la
```

Here is a video showing this and explaining it a bit more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-61_kIikldQ

I am not sure how its showing the files in your case. Maybe you got a stale docker environment with files from previous runs because of a bug. I just tested it and I don't have any files without running the checkout first.